# How can I add side panel for RC DOCK

Tags: reactjs

I am using rc dock in a project. Everything is perfect for me, but I have a new request.

I want to manage the docks on the screen through a panel. A panel that turns them on and off.

For example, if necessary, such as the side and bottom panels in Intellij IDEA.

Is it possible for me to do this, I am asking for your support.